# XStream Java display progress

Tags: java, xstream

is there a possibility to display the progress of the serialization/deserialization process? Because I have a huge amount of Objects (200.000) and it takes 10 to 20 seconds, so I want to show the user a progress bar. Or is there a better solution/library?

Comment: do you have the timing problems when you create a String (String xml = xstream.toXML() ) or does this happen when you write the String into a File ?

Comment: Writing the String, saving to disc is really fast, it takes less than 3 sec (SSD)

Comment: look at my answer - i guess you have a list or a tree and therefore you know how much item are within your 'collection'... then you can increase the counter whenever an item is worked on (Converter.WriteItem(..) )... i don't think you'll have problems with updating your progressbar, but let me know if this solution worked for you ...

Comment: Rather than building a string and then writing that string to a file you should look at serializing directly to the file in the first place.  You can do this by using the two-argument `toXML` method that takes an `OutputStream`.

Comment: very good argument @IanRoberts - i strongly agree with you! and still you can overwrite the Converter to supply your progress bar (excuse my english again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a custom Converter...

i assume that you have a collection in wich resides your data...

```
ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();  //example list
stringList.add("abc"); //example data
stringList.add("abc"); //example data
stringList.add("abc"); //example data
stringList.add("abc"); //example data

XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.alias("string", String.class ); //example aliasing

Mapper mapper = xstream.getMapper();

CollectionConverter aColCon = new CollectionConverter(mapper) {

    @Override
    protected void writeItem(Object item, MarshallingContext context, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer){
        super.writeItem(item, context, writer);
        System.out.println("write object item"+item);
        //TODO your progress bar here!

    }
};

xstream.registerConverter(aColCon);
String asXml = xstream.toXML(stringList);
System.out.println(asXml);
```

this is the output:

```
write object itemabc
write object itemabc
write object itemabc
write object itemabc
<list>
  <string>abc</string>
  <string>abc</string>
  <string>abc</string>
  <string>abc</string>
</list>
```

have a look at http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/collections/AbstractCollectionConverter.html#readItem%28com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamReader,%20com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.UnmarshallingContext,%20java.lang.Object%29 there you can find you best converter...

Comment: i would be glad to see what you have produced!

Comment: Here my solution: https://github.com/schnawel007/ExtendedXStream/tree/master/ExtendedXStream/src/de/joshuaschnabel/extendedxstream

Comment: thanks for posting your full solution! you seem to write good code, keep up that great work!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can extend a [HierarchicalStreamWriter](http://xstream.codehaus.org/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/io/HierarchicalStreamWriter.html) and add some progress information to [`startNode`](http://xstream.codehaus.org/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/io/HierarchicalStreamWriter.html#setValue(java.lang.String))

```
@XStreamAlias("entity")
private static class Entity {
    String foo;
    String bar;
}

private static class ProgressIndicationWriter extends PrettyPrintWriter {
    public ProgressIndicationWriter(Writer writer, NameCoder nameCoder) {
        super(writer, nameCoder);
    }

    @Override
    public void startNode(String name) {
        System.out.print("writing node " + name + ".. ");
        super.startNode(name);
        System.out.println("OK");
    }
}

private static class ProgressIndicationDriver extends XppDriver {
    @Override
    public HierarchicalStreamWriter createWriter(Writer out) {
        return new ProgressIndicationWriter(out, getNameCoder());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final XStream xstream = new XStream(new ProgressIndicationDriver());
    xstream.autodetectAnnotations(true);

    final Entity myEntity = new Entity();
    myEntity.foo = "Lorem";
    myEntity.bar = "Ipsum";

    final String xml = xstream.toXML(myEntity);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(xml);
}
```

And the output is

```
writing node entity.. OK
writing node foo.. OK
writing node bar.. OK

<entity>
  <foo>Lorem</foo>
  <bar>Ipsum</bar>
</entity>
```

This should be more generic than the approach to write custom converter.